# google maps- how to position pop up address bubble on embedded map

Tags: google-maps

I have a google map to embed using the simple iframe code. my problem is on page load on a desktop the pop up address bubble is halfway off the screen. is there away to position it on page load? please see screens below:

[image: How it looks now]

[image: How I want it to look]

here is the code:

```
 <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="Some map"></iframe><br /><small><a href="some map" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved it, you have to position the map how you want it to display before copying the embed code.